# Explanation of voltage $= dW/dq$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, potential-energy, voltage

I recently started to learn about circuit theory, and in the book it straight up defines voltage as $ dW/dq$, or the derivative of energy with respect to charge. The thing is, I always thought of charge as something discrete, but by this definition it seems like it is assumed to be continuous. I would be very grateful if someone could please explain this definition.

Comment: For macroscopic systems, charge as a continuous quantity is a good approximation. For a small capacitor of 10muF and a voltage of 10 V, the charge in the capacitor would be about 0.1 mCoulombs which is 14 orders of magnitude larger than the charge of a single electron.

Comment: @Mauricio Please consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: I think someone can explain this on a particle-by-particle basis by thinking carefully about exactly where "q" is.  One electron can enter a higher energy state and be in a succession of hybridized states as it begins moving from place to place.  (If you can observe the motion of the electron leaving an atom at one side, it is *not* in a standard atomic orbital) I suspect one electron's energy can vary continuously as it crosses a gap, and the charge "on" one electrode might be seen to do so also when considered this way? Someone familiar with this can probably say it better if it is true.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the applications within the boundaries of circuit theory, you assume the charge is continuous. Even if you would like to take into account the discrete nature of the electrons, you model it as a background noise called shot noise (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise). Thus, the definition makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The most common situation in which a voltage difference is doing work on a charge occurs when there is current flow in a circuit.  The charge is continuously leaving (and entering) the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

> ...the book it straight up defines voltage as $ dW/dq$

I've never seen it defined in this differential form. But the definition of the voltage $V$, or potential difference, between two points is defined as the work per unit charge required to move the charge between the points.

> The thing is, I always thought of charge as something discrete, but by
> this definition it seems like it is assumed to be continuous.

Charge is discrete. It is the charge of a single electron or proton. But the unit of charge in the definition of voltage is taken as the Coulomb (C), where 1 C = 6.241 x 10$^{18}$ protons or electrons. Then, given the unit of work as the Joule, 1 volt = 1 Joule/Coulomb (J/C).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$W=Vq$$
$$V=\frac{dW}{dq}$$
If you charge a sphere. Then you will say that there's huge amount of charge for what we macroscopically see that the sphere is continuously charged. For that reason, we take the surface charge density or volume charge density for these case rather than discrete charges. In macroscopic world, Its really hard to take a look at charges as discrete for a charged material.
<strike>I won't excuse if you look at them as discrete microscopically.</strike>

For that reason, we macroscopically write that $$\mathrm dq\sim\lambda \ \mathrm dl \ \sim \sigma \ \mathrm dA \ \sim \rho \ \mathrm dV$$